# ImageMagick on Heroku won't take -fill as 'white'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm running a Rails 3.2 app locally using MiniMagick with ImageMagick and this piece of code

```
img.combine_options do |c| 
    c.gravity 'Center'
    c.font "#{::Rails.root}/public/fonts/Impact.ttf" 
    c.pointsize '125'
    c.kerning '-6'
    c.draw "text 0,-120 '#{self.line1}'"
    c.draw "text 0,-16 '#{self.line2}'"
    c.draw "text 0,88 '#{self.line3}'"
    c.fill "#ffffff"
end
```

Which works fine locally, the text is written on top of the image as expected and comes out white.

Once I deploy this to Heroku (Cedar), I get no errors but the text is written on top of the image in black.

This is the first time I've used MiniMagick and ImageMagick together on Heroku so, maybe I'm missing something with color depth? Is it that the image is PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After properly reading the [command line options available](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) to MiniMagick via ImageMagick for the 'draw' option I found this paragraph that solved the issue:

*Options are processed in command line order so be sure to use these options before the -draw option.*

So by changing the order the options are passed in, to move the fill color to above the 'draw' param solved it, as below:

```
img.combine_options do |c| 
  c.gravity 'Center'
  c.font "#{::Rails.root}/public/fonts/Impact.ttf"
  c.fill "#ffffff"
  c.pointsize '125'
  c.kerning '-6'
  c.draw "text 0,-120 '#{self.line1}'"
  c.draw "text 0,-16 '#{self.line2}'" 
  c.draw "text 0,88 '#{self.line3}'"
end
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't happen locally? I run into the exactly same problem.

Comment: Initially I suspected possible different versions, but then it makes sense if you read the above example that you SHOULD set the font and the color before any text is written to the image.